# Why does Tomcat work with port 8080 but not 80?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, port, firewall

I have started and tested Tomcat under Port 8080 (default). Now I altered the connector port  to 80 and restarted Tomcat, nothing will show on my minimal Debian 6.0 installation. Now where is the trick here?

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Did you get a BindException, perhaps, in catalina.out? There's a fair chance something else in the system is already bound to port 80.

Comment: Maybe another service is running on that port already

Comment: First thing to do : look at the logs (in the tomcat/logs directory)

Comment: I would like to check out the log, there is none at /etc/tomcat6, where would the log folder most likely be?

Comment: @Jack Murphy: *(not an answer, hence the comment)* for what it is worth I never ever run Tomcat as root nor sudo'ed or anything like that.  Actually on Linux I don't even install Java as root: I install Java in a user account, using only that user's privileges.  I then run Tomcat on ports 8080 / 8443.  The system is however configured (as root), to transparently redirect port 80 to 8080 etc. (using *iptables*).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464926/linux-in-ec2amazon-cannot-use-port-80-for-tomcat

Answer (score 31, accepted):

go to /etc/default/tomcat6 and change `#AUTHBIND=no` to `AUTHBIND=yes`

```
 # If you run Tomcat on port numbers that are all higher than 1023, then you
 # do not need authbind.  It is used for binding Tomcat to lower port numbers.
 # NOTE: authbind works only with IPv4.  Do not enable it when using IPv6.
 # (yes/no, default: no)
 #AUTHBIND=no
```

Comment: also see http://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/tomcat-6-binding-to-a-privileged-port-on-debianubuntu/

Answer (score 12):

Two typical reasons:

- You quite possibly don't have permission to listen to a port lower than 1024 (usually requires administrative privileges, e.g. being `root`)
- Something else may already be listening on port 80 (e.g. apache)

Comment: @Romain: Well, root or a similarly privileged account. Have edited to clarify. I *believe* 1024 would be okay (i.e. it's only 0-1023 which require privilege, but I could be wrong)

Comment: Nothing else is listening on port 80. I am root but I am executing it with /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start

Answer (score 11):

Did you start Tomcat on port 80 as root?  You have to be root to bind to ports <= 1024 in Linux.

Comment: Worth noting: starting Tomcat as `root` is generally a bad idea, security-wise, unless it is able (and configured) to switch its user to a non-privileged user after binding (which wasn't possible last time I checked).

Comment: I started Tomcat using /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start logged in with the root account. Can I modify it so I can start it under port 80?

Comment: The tomcat configuration files are what determine which port to use, how you start the process doesn't really matter.  Chances are you either have something else listening on port 80.  Try running: netstat -an | grep 80
That will let you know if something is already listening on port 80.

Comment: @Romain what would you say is the best way to make Tomcat accessible on port 80? Install both Apache httpd server and Tomcat and then use Apache httpd server to proxy to Tomcat using mod_proxy?

Comment: @arya I pues so - Tomcat + some reverse proxy (Apache, Nginx, whatever suits your use-case best)

Answer (score 11):

If nothing of the commented before works (like it happened to me), you can direct the traffic from the port `80` to the `8080`.

To do it:

http://forum.slicehost.com/index.php?p=/discussion/2497/iptables-redirect-port-80-to-port-8080/p1

In a nutshell, type this three commands in a terminal:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: it will be just an extreme case, as you have mentioned "If nothing of the commented before have worked".

Comment: Other readers are seeing something that I'm missing:

* This is simple and accomplishes the goal without having to install & administer `authbind`.
* Tomcat listens on the low-number ports.
* Tomcat runs as a non-privileged user.

Why is this an extreme case solution?

Comment: This solution isn't great because the end user will see the port number in their URL and see a URL change.

Comment: @alexk I'm not having the URL change issue with this solution -I know this is a really old thread.

Answer (score 2):

Run your startup script as root after changing the binding.

```
sudo ./<path to tomcat bin director>/startup.sh
```

Comment: Perfect solution, saved my day

Comment: Correct answer for *nix but what about Windows?

Answer (score 0):

stop apache service and then run tomcat you should be good , by default apache is running on port 80

Comment: What about the fact ports <= 1024 are privileged?

Comment: Nothing in the OP mentions that. You shouldn't assume.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is nothing running on 80 since its a basic debian with only SSH installed, I added java and tomcat with apt-get.

Comment: There is no Apache running nor anything else at port 80

Answer (score 0):

You can use authbind/privbind or capabilities to bind to port 80.