# Tomcat 7.0.32 applications doesn't work after I change default port

Tags: tomcat

I have changed default ports at server.xml file (8080 -> 9080 and 8443 -> 9443) and after that, all applications stopped to work. I always receive 404 Not Found. Like /manager or /samples

Should I touch any other configuration file?

Windows 64 bits with Tomcat 7.0.32

Comment: where did you change it, server.xml?

Comment: Yes. File /conf/serve.xml in several places. Basically everywhere there is 8080 I changed to 9080, and the same with 8443.

Comment: did you change the URL to reflect the new port?

Comment: Yes of course. The old ports don't answer 404. Directly don't connect.

Comment: Take a look at this , this works for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450045/why-does-tomcat-work-with-port-8080-but-not-80

Answer (score 1):

Forget it. It seems a browser cache problem.
From remote browser it worked...
Sorry.