# jelastic grails redirects http to https

Tags: grails, https, spring-security, tomcat6, jelastic

I have one domain app.mydomain.com which is mapped with A record to public IP (from tomcat server that belongs to mysub.jelastic.dogado.eu)
I've configured SSL custom certificates and all HTTPS requests works very well.

All i need is that my app to use just HTTPS, all HTTP requests to be redirected to HTTPS, 
Acordingly with spring security plugin (1.2.7.4 that i have on my app) i configured in this way:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 8080
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 8443
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = 'http'
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = 'https'
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
            '/**':               'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
    ]
```

On localhost it is working very good, all http requests were redirected to https but in jelastic nothig happend. I tried many configuration, replacing https port to 8743/443, but the same results. Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Catalin

Comment: "but in jelastic nothig happend." - what do you mean exactly? A redirect loop, a timeout, or no redirect at all? Also as per my answer please provide your environment topology.

Answer (score 1):

The X-Forwarded-Proto header is only set if you have a load balancer in your environment (or using the shared resolver, but since you're using a custom SSL certificate that cannot apply in this case).

If you don't have a load balancer in your environment, that is why the check does not work - since those headers are simply not set.

If you do have a load balancer, all requests to your Tomcat are directed to port 80 (redirected via port forwarding to 8080); that includes requests sent to https (because the load balancer performs 'SSL offload' in this case. Therefore you are seeking an impossible combination in your grails rules (8743 and X-Forwarded-Proto). Depending on your environment topology you will have one of these cases or the other, but not both.

EDIT: You should also double-check your server.xml to make sure you have this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" />
```

Note the `redirectPort` value; it should be 443 because this is the port that will be sent to the browser for a redirect - with a load balancer (or Jelastic Shared Resolver) proxying the requests, the browser needs to request on port 443 (even though the Tomcat SSL connector is configured on 8743 - if applicable), because the proxy uses standard port numbering (i.e. https:// without any port number = 443).

Even if you are working with a standalone Tomcat (no load balancer, and not via the Jelastic Shared Resolver), those requests to 443 will be automatically forwarded to 8743 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Damien, your answer solved the issue. For anyone interested this is the configuration(Config.groovy):

```
 production {
    grails.app.context = "/"        
    grails.serverURL = "https://yourdomain.com"
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 80
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
            '/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
    ]
  }
```

Put this in server.xml:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="443" />
```

I suppose 8080 also works.

Make war, deploy.

Comment: You can't usually run Tomcat directly on port 80 (on Linux) unless you make special provisions - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450045/why-does-tomcat-work-with-port-8080-but-not-80 for details why. That is why Jelastic uses 8080 and redirects traffic hitting port 80 to 8080 for you (so the actual connector is on 8080, but the URL entered by the user doesn't need a port appending (like :8080).