# Tomcat7 works with port 8080 but not at 80, Windows7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have the same problem as

[Why does Tomcat work with port 8080 but not 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450045/why-does-tomcat-work-with-port-8080-but-not-80)

I have changed the server.xml like this:

```
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

What is different is that I am using Tomcat7 in Windows rather than using tomcat6 in Linux.

But the answer to this is  "to /etc/default/tomcat6 and change #AUTHBIND=no to AUTHBIND=yes".

But how can I can find this file in Windows7, I search tomcat7 in my computer and could not find any configuration file like this.

The logs written in Console is still like:

> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
>
> Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

And I am still able to get access to my servlet using port 0f 8080 instead of 80.

Comment: How you are starting tomcat ?

Comment: In the eclipse tab, server , restart.

Comment: So go to your server, double click on it and on the right side of the panel you will see the port that that Tomcat is using. The eclipse has an embedded tomcat installation and that is the one you are starting. See on this image: http://telestax.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Eclipse_tomcat_installation_server_settings.png just searched on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, tomcat has a different configuration altogether.

1. Go to Server Tab
2. Double Click on Tomcat
3. A Tomcat window will open up
4. Go to Ports Tab
5. Change the `HTTP/1.1` port number.
6. Restart Tomcat

Comment: Thank you! I make it! So, what will the server.xml impact on my tomcat now if I am using eclipse?

Comment: It simply won't. The server settings used via eclipse overrides the default settings in the `server.xml`