# How can I change my Apache Tomcat server to serve port 80 instead of 8080 in an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running Apache Tomcat.

If I access `IpAddress:8080` it's working.

I want to change it to `IpAddress:80`.

I've tried all the solutions given for this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80) and nothing works for me.

Ports 8080, 80, 443 & 8443 are all allowed in security group inbound rules.

I'm using

- ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20210415
- apache-tomcat-9.0.54 installed via tar.gz

1. changed port number in server.xml restarted the tomcat server, It didn't work.

```
sudo vi /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/server.xml

<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443"/>
```

2. Tried below steps It didn't work.

```sh
sudo apt-get install authbind 
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown ubuntu /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

also I can't find `#AUTHBIND=no`  anywhere in my machine. I am logging in as ubuntu user.

I've spent almost 2 days for this.

What is the issue?

Comment: Is this an EC2 "VM"?

Comment: Yes, @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: from inside the EC2 does it work when you curl localhost:80 ?

Comment: ```wget http://localhost``` response is  ```failed : Connection refused``` and 

```curl localhost:80``` response is ```curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused``` @AnisSmail

Comment: are you sure tomcat is running, can you check the logs ?

Comment: I also found this answer, it seems that there're extra steps you're missing to properly configure authbind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043792/could-anyone-please-tell-me-where-is-autobind-in-server-xml-in-tomcat-9-as-menti

Comment: I did follow the solution in that question.. its shows the below error
``` sudo systemctl status tomcat```
the command gives the output as 
```
Oct 23 16:16:04 -101 systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
startup.sh[11789]: Existing PID file found during start.
startup.sh[11789]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
startup.sh[11789]: Tomcat started.
systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:16: Executable path is not absolute: authbind --deep /home/ubuntu/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```